# Could not reliably determine the server’s fully qualified domain name

Tags: apache, ubuntu

На свежий Linux уставлен Apache 2. После перезагрузки

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

пишет

> Could not reliably determine the server’s fully qualified domain name

Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
2. У Вас поднят DNS сервер bind9, если да, то покопайте в его направлении.
3. Слишком мало информации, можно поподробнее расписать, что конкретно вам не нравится? Не стартует демон или криво работает?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Какие это проблемы влечет, я еще не понял, просто странно, что апач выкидывает предупреждения. Все исправилось после добавления ServerName в `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.